What is this RED PROHIBITED ICON showing everywhere on my system?
I'm currently running Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS and recently there has been a red prohibited icon showing everywhere on my system.
I updated the system not long ago, but the issue started some weeks after the update so I am not sure they are related.
This red circle appears on the top bar menu, built-in apps, and manually installed ones. I believe it's an icon issue but I'm not sure
Any suggestions on what may be causing it?
This image shows that the red circle appears in different parts of the system.


That indicates missing icons.  Did you do a complete install or an upgrade in place?  It sounds like this is actually a problem with your theme missing files/icons

I also have this problem. I finished work yesterday afternoon and this morning when starting up lots of icons are missing. I did not manually install anything during the night. Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Linux DellPrecision-5560 6.5.0-35-generic #35~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue May  7 09:00:52 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

if you run sudo apt update ; sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^ (note the caret on the end) does it install any 'missing' packages? This may resolve the issue, if it does.

Tried, icons not restored yet.

Could you try this answer. It is quite old but Gnome may be still using same icon cache tool. Probably, need login/logout or even reboot after regenerating the cache.

The icons that you are missing called Desktop Icons NG Ding.
If you have Shell Extension or Shell Extensions Manager installed you can check that.
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions

Or Shell Extension manager, with Shell Extension Manager you can find a lot of other extensions.
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager

To get the icons back
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng

Then after logging off or rebooting should the icons show.

Tried, icons not restored yet.

@mcabreb check your messages

I tried that but did not get the icons back. I reinstalled GNOME and there were no icons. Next I installed KDE and I had most of the icons, though some of them are still missing, like some of the arrows that appear in pop up messages when selecting files, so I leave it at that. When I have time I will reinstall ubuntu again.

Somehow this answer was auto selected for the bounty, though it did not help me.

@mcabreb Pls read the rules and guidelines for the bounty https://askubuntu.com/help/bounty , I have been trying to get hold of you for 7 days now. Can you connect to https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/153654/discussion-what-is-this-red-prohibited-icon-showing-everywhere-on-my-system and there is also user.dz higher up that has provided a link if you want to try.

Yep, no problem you can keep the bounty. I was in a deadline and needed my computer working so I put a bounty in this question, as it was exactly the same problem for me. I just removed gnome and went on with kde, themes and colored things mean nothing to me I just need the computer to finish the projects and I could not work with no icons. No biggie, really. Thanks for all the suggestions and keep the good work. Thanks!

I had the same issue. For some reason, gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders command didn't work after the update. Once I fixed this command, the icons started appearing again.
First check if gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders file is located in the /usr/lib. If not install it.
find . -name 'gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders'

Next link it to the /usr/local/bin/
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders /usr/local/bin/gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders

And then run the following command.
gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders --update-cache

